# What HTTP status codes need to be checked for this network task to perform smoothly?

Tags: algorithms, http

My office department logs in to the ISP Server through a keep-alive-browser login page. This, for better performance, is encapsulated in to a small python script.
This is what it does (Pseudo code)

```
1.CheckForActiveInternet
2.if not active
     Login
     KeepAlive
3.else
     report
```

In step 1, a host like "www.google.com" is checked for active connection. A status code is returned and this is exactly what my doubt is; what would this code be? **200** or **202**? Incase google redirects to .co.** urls the status code would be **302** which even complicates it further since our ISP redirects too, when there is no active internet connection.
You could see that if we check **302** for deciding on weather or not we'd be needing a login, it could be either the google redirecting or our ISP itself. So what could be done here? The current script checks:

```
if status in (200, 202, ""):
    Connection is Active
```

This is quite vague isn't it? When is an empty string returned as status code? A non-redirecting site like wikipedia.org might do the trick I thought, but I don't know how feasible this method would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft does this in Windows by attempting to download a specific URL and checking whether it has specific, static content:

When the PC seems to be connected to the network, Windows will download [`http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt`](http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt) (and [`http://ipv6.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt`](http://ipv6.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt) to check IPv6 connectivity) and check that the response body contains the string "Microsoft NCSI". If it does not, then something is wrong with the Internet connectivity, and the [yellow triangle with the exclamation mark](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126135%28WS.10%29.aspx) appears in the user's taskbar.

You can use a similar algorithm in your own program. By checking for the returned text to match something you expect, from a known web site which does not return 302 redirects, you can be sure whether the computer has Internet connectivity.